# Import a random csv as a table on the fly - Postgresql and Python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am using a pgadmin client. I have multiple csv files.

I would like to import each csv file as a table.

When I tried the below

a) Click create table

b) Enter the name of table and save it.

c) I see the table name

d) Click on "Import csv"

e) selected columns as "header"

f) Clicked "Import"

But I got an error message as below

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY Test_table, line 2: "32,F,52,Single,WHITE,23/7/2180 12:35,25/7/2180..."
```

I also tried the python psycopg2 version as shown below

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("host='xxx.xx.xx.x' port='5432' dbname='postgres' user='abc' password='xxx'")
cur = conn.cursor()
f = open(r'test.csv', 'r')
cur.copy_from(f,public.test, sep=',') #while I see 'test' table under my schema, how can I give here the schema name etc. I don't know wht it says table not defined
f.close()
```

> UndefinedTable: relation "public.test" does not exist

May I check whether it is possible to import some random csv as table using pgadmin import?

Comment: `test' is not defined` is because it should be `cur.copy_from(f,'test', sep=',')` The `NameError`  is coming from Python not Postgres as Python is looking for a variable of `test`.  The `extra data after last expected column` is occurring because the row is not being properly quoted and there is something causing an extra column to be created from the incoming data. You will need to show the complete row of data, as well as the table schema to get a better answer.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver - I updated the error message. But I have already created a just an empty table (`test`) with no columns under `public` schema. I didn't add columns to it because I want the table to be created on the fly. When I import/read the csv data into postgresql db, I want the table to have these headers from csv

Comment: That is not going to happen, `COPY` needs to have a table with at least the same number of columns(and of correct type) as the input data. The table can have more columns then the input data, but then you would have to supply a column list to `COPY`. You would need to do this as a two step process, where you read the header  and create a table(using some script) and then `COPY` into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas will do this easily. Create a table with a structure as some csv.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

The csv is first read by read_csv to a Dataframe

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Regards Niels

As I understand the requirement, a new table is wanted for every csv. The code below illustrates that. It can be customized and datatypes can be elaborated, see the documentation for Pandas.DataFrame.to_sql. I think, actually, that the heavy lifting is done by [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

```
import io
import os

import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

buf_t1 = io.StringIO()
buf_t1.write("a,b,c,d\n")
buf_t1.write("1,2,3,4\n")
buf_t1.seek(0)
df_t1 = pd.read_csv(buf_t1)
df_t1.to_sql(name="t1", con="postgresql+psycopg2://host/db", index=False, if_exists='replace')
#
buf_t2 = io.StringIO()
buf_t2.write("x,y,z,t\n")
buf_t2.write("1,2,3,'Hello World'\n")
buf_t2.seek(0)
df_t2 = pd.read_csv(buf_t2)
df_t2.to_sql(name="t2", con="postgresql+psycopg2://host/db", index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

This will result in two new tables, t1 and t2. Defined as like this:

```
create table t1
(
    a bigint,
    b bigint,
    c bigint,
    d bigint
);
create table t2
(
    x bigint,
    y bigint,
    z bigint,
    t text
);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Upvoted. Can the same be done for Postgresql table?

Comment: But it asks me to create a table with columns. What I have is only a table (no column names). I want the columns in csv to be used as header for table

Comment: Again not going to happen, That would require a whole sequence of `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` statements.

Comment: Let's take @AdrianKlaver point a step further assuming you can identify the column names. Then to create ALTER statements you need to determine the data type? can it be null?, is it limited to certain values?, or relate to columns in other tables?, must it be unique? ... I guess every column could be defined as: text (with no restrictions), null-able, and no relationships. The result - no data nor relational integrity. And what happens when a user puts in a column that does not belong?  It would be non-performant and a maintenance nightmare.  In short the worse thing for you is to succeed.